# Rails Pg error "database removed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a problem on large highload project. We use old rails (2.3) and pg database. And sometimes calling pages we receive problem "PGError Database Removed". 
I tried to google it, but there's only "Database dropped". 
It looks like connection lost because of timeout, but it has different error messages.
Where can i find any info about that problem?

Comment: grep the source code for the old Rails and old Pg gem you are using. It might be enlightening.

Comment: I've already tried to do it, there's no such keywords

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've solved the problem by myself. The problem was in pgbouncer on our servers. 1.4.1+ version doesn't have such bug with disconnecting by timeout, but we had 1.3.9.